# Stopping the page refresh - not working with clear function

Tags: javascript

This is code to display a spinner while image is loading and then show the image when it is done. Also, this page needs to be auto-refreshed every 5 seconds and the refreshing to be stopped at 11 seconds, ie refresh twice alltogether. But this doesn't work. The spinner code is in the css file. This does not work - keeps refreshing over and over - the timeout gets reset, tried using var to assign as well no joy. Any help appreciated highly.

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Cache-Control" CONTENT="max-age=0">
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Cache-Control" CONTENT="no-cache">
<META http-equiv="expires" content="0">
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Expires" CONTENT="Tue, 01 Jan 1980 1:00:00 GMT">
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Pragma" CONTENT="no-cache">
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/graph.css" type="text/css" media="screen, projection">
<script src="/javascript/jquery-latest.js" type="text/javascript">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var img = new Image(); img.height=600; img.width=2000;
    $(img).load(function () {
    $(this).css('display','none');
    $(this).animate({ opacity: 0.25 }).fadeIn("slow");
    $('#loader').append(this);
    $(this).animate({ opacity: 1 })
    }).error(function () {
    }).attr('src', 'xyz.png');
    var timer = function() { window.location.reload(true);};
        window["reload_timer"] = setTimeout(timer, 5000);
    var timer2 = function() {     
        clearTimeout(window["reload_timer"]);
        clearTimeout(window["reload_timer2"]);};
        window["reload_timer2"] = setTimeout(timer2, 11000);
</script>
</head>
<body id = "page"><div id="loader" class="loading">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Well, you are **reloading** the page...

Comment: do you really have to reload the page or is your intent just to reload the image twice?

Comment: image will do too...if it works...because this code will go into an iframe on the main window, i have tried reload() in the iframe but same problem there the clearTimeout never gets invoked or it keeps reseting the timer at every reload.

Answer (score 2):

You could try reloading the page URL with a parameter attached to it.  Then you could read in the parameter with JavaScript and use that to know how many times the page has refreshed so you stop after 2 refreshes.

Otherwise the page is stateless - the same exact page will load as before, with no knowledge if it was already loaded or not.  By introducing this URL parameter you can track some sort of state.

Comment: URL is a image, i tried ?(value) from a static var but even that gets reset back to 0 after the reload()

Comment: How can this be achieved? can you please give me an example?

Comment: Page doesn't have a URL because this html content will be written inside an iframe onload using parent.frames['iframe2'].document.write("content")

Comment: If you're just using an iframe to generate content and insert it into the page, why not generate content and load it into a div?  You could build it externally with AJAX or internally with JavaScript.  This doesn't require an page refreshes, just some dynamic content.

Answer (score 0):

When you reload the page, the page forgets it has already been reloaded, so in fact your code never reaches timer2

Comment: I think you are right. How can i fix this. can i put the timer2 in front of timer? will that work?